# XPath query returns no results in Yahoo Pipes

Tags: xpath, yahoo-pipes

Trying to get all titles from http://www.112.ru/services/wanted/people/index.shtml?roztype=1
using *Yahoo Pipes* `Xfetch` module.

My query `//span[@class='uchbold']` select all titles in *Firepath* successfully. But in *Yahoo Pipes* and *Hpple* there is no results.

Comment: There may be people who are prepared to click on a link in www.112.ru. Others (including me) are less trustful, and will therefore not answer your question. It's much better to copy a sufficient extract of the XML into the question.

Comment: @MichaelKay As Jens found it out it was a problem due to async loading parts of the data. In case I put only html source here, it would be impossible to answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These class attributes are inserted by a JavaScript which isn't executed using Yahoo Pipes and Hpple.

Also the contents are loaded by ajax, you will have to trace the ajax calls and develop against this interface.

Using Firebug I could trace it loading

```
http://www.112.ru/publish/00/01/0508.01/2012/08//contents.xml
```

and lots of other "contents.xml" files which returned 404 errors. It contains contents in form of elements like

```
<view file="0901156380089d71_0508.01_00_01.full.shtml" format="full" indexed="true"/>
```

which seem to link again to some HTML snippets containing the actual data.

Comment: Can you please recommend any tutorial/documentation for further reading?

Comment: You will have to read and analyze the JavaScript loading the files to somehow get an idea on how they're loading the data and how to do it without JavaScript. Once you know how to determine the URLs to load, you need to fetch and combine them all. I'm sorry I can't help you any further as I do not know Yahoo Pipes in detail. Or you build some kind of proxy using Node.JS or some other tools and use it to evaluate the JavaScript before parsing with Yahoo Pipes, but I guess that's even more difficult (and requires a server).